# Blue Yeti failed component identification

Tags: identification

I have a Blue Yeti microphone that has had an on board component fail (lack of audio out and extreme heat from the chip in question). Based on some tracing it likely has something to do with the 3.5 millimeter headphone output jack and the volume knob.

The text on the chip appears to be AIF BAN or A1F BAN. I do not see any obvious manufacturer markings.

[image: Unknown IC, zoomed in, with ruler for scale]

Image of chip with ruler for scale.

[image: Blue Yeti Digital Rev8c board]

Whole board in context with the chip indicated with an arrow and the surrounding components circled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"AIF" could be [MAX97220AETE+](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/256/MAX97220A-MAX97220E-5002.pdf), which is a headphone / line amplifier chip.

Perhaps compare the traces with the pin-out to verify that it is indeed this chip.